# Find the value of $x$ in the triangle $ABC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

A triangle $ABC$ has angle $A=2y$ and angle $C=y$. Furthermore, $AB=x,BC=x+2$, and $AC=5$. Solve for $x$.

I tried this question whole day but could not find solution of it . Please help me

Comment: Use cosine rule and sine rule once each to get simultaneous equations. Cosine rule: $X^2=(X+2)^2+25-10(X+2) \cos y$ Sine rule: $X \sin 2y = (X+2) \sin y $

Comment: Since you worked on this question all day, please add some of your work and attempts directly into your post.  Claiming to have tried a question for a whole day, is not the same as providing evidence of such work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AD$ be a bisector of $\Delta ABC$ and $AD=y$.

Thus, $AD=DC=y$ and $BD=x+2-y$.

Now, since $\Delta{ABD}\sim\Delta{CBA}$, we obtain
$$\frac{y}{5}=\frac{x}{x+2}=\frac{x+2-y}{x},$$ which gives
$xy=5x-2y$ and $x^2=(x+2)^2-xy-2y$, which is $xy=4x+4-2y$

and from here $4x-2y+4=5x-2y$ or $x=4$ and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Source:** ... (To be completed by this answerer.)

I applied the sine theorem to get $\cos y$ the the cosine theorem to solve for $x$

Comment: You've just complied with the "do my homework for me" request from this asker, and you've reinforced this asker's avoidance of effort, because you've verified: "I'll just rely on some gullible answerer to do everything for me", especially those groveling for rep points."  Where did you get this image?  From what source?

Answer (score 0):

From the sine theorem you get $cosy=\tfrac{x+2}{2x}$.
By half-angle formula in any triangle: $$cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\sqrt{\tfrac{s(s-a)}{bc}}$$, where $s$-semiperimeter, $a,b,c$ - corresponding sides of triangle $ABC$.
Let $\alpha=2y$, $s=3.5+x; a=x+2;b=x; c=5.$ Then: $$\tfrac{x+2}{2x}=\sqrt{\tfrac{1.5(3.5+x)}{5x}}$$
After squaring both sides and by elementary manipulation you left with quadratic equation:
$$x^2+x-20=0$$
So, $x=4$.